# onActivityResult не запускается

Tags: java, android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо вызвать метод onActivityResult для MainActivity. В этой активности, я перехожу сначала в активность "Поиск", а потом на активность "Добавить участника". После того, как в активности "Добавить участника", нажимаешь на кнопку "Добавить участника". Она должна вызвать onActivityResult у MainActivity.

Код из AddMember для вызова MainActivity:

```
Intent intentDealCreation = new Intent(AddMemberInfoActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

 startActivityForResult(intentDealCreation,1);
```

Код в MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Привет, я тут!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: активити ты стартуешься с requestCode = 1, а в онРезалте не проверяешь на него и хочешь поймать это активити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно тогда вызывать из активности поиска вызывать startActivityForResult для 
AddMemberInfoActivity, по вызову AddMember вы должны передать данные обратно в активность поиска и закрыть AddMemberInfoActivity. Это делается так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

В активности поиска вы попадете в onActivityResult там вы опять должны передать данные обратно в MainActivity и закрыть активность поиска. И только тогда вы попадете в onActivityResult для MainActivity. 
А сейчас у вас код на запуск новой MainActivity. Вы в onActivityResult не попадете никак таким способом.